# How to save the order of buttons after dragging and dropping all buttons in dropzone in random manner?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save the order of buttons in the sequence they are dragged and dropped in the blue drop-zone from red one. For e.g. Getting Feedback and Ideas could be 1, Scattered Work and Content
could be 2 and so on. It depends on what order user selects. But I need to get and save the order sequence.

[image]

For Button1 I am able to drop it in the blue drop-zone. I tried document.querySelectorAll("#button1,#button2,#button3,#button4,#button5") but it is not working. How to achieve this for all Buttons and save their sequence numbers?
The code I have tried so far is as below:

```js
const draggableElement = document.querySelector("#button1");
draggableElement.addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", draggableElement.id);
});
for (const dropZone of document.querySelectorAll(".drop-zone")) {
  //when draggable element is over a dz
  dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropZone.classList.add("drop-zone--over");
  });
  //when draggable element no longer over dz
  dropZone.addEventListener("dragLeave", e => {
    dropZone.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
  });
  //when draggable element is dropped onto dz
  dropZone.addEventListener("drop", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const droppedElementId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    const droppedElement = document.getElementById(droppedElementId);
    dropZone.appendChild(droppedElement);
    dropZone.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <div class="drop-zone" style="border-color:#DE4031">
      <div>
        <button class="button" id="button1" draggable="true">Miscommunication & Misinterpretation </button>
        <button class="button" id="button2" draggable="true">Communication Delays</button>
        <button class="button" id="button3" draggable="true">Scattered Work and Content </button>
        <button class="button" id="button4" draggable="true">Sharing Work with Others</button>
        <button class="button" id="button5" draggable="true">Getting Feedback and Ideas
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-zone" style="border-color:#31CFDE">
    </div>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: you are just select `button1` how do you expect that this code can work for all buttons when you're not select them yet

Comment: That is what my question is. I am not able to do it for all buttons. I am getting error when I include all buttons with querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. i would like to remember you to make head tag alone and body tag alone because everyone means something - head first and close it then body don't add the body inside of the head tag
2. you need to get all those elements by class name and make a loop
3. try to use normal function at this case not arrow function to be able to get element id directly by using `this` keyword because arrow function refer to the window while function referring to the element
4. If you want to use arrow function replace `this.id` with `e.target.id`
5. i i added the edited piece of code inside a comment

> Here's Your Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <style>
        .drop-zone {
             border: 3px dotted;
        }
        .drop-zone:nth-child(2) {
             height: 50vh;;
        }
    </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="drop-zone" style="border-color:#DE4031">
      <div>
        <button class="button" id="button1" draggable="true">Miscommunication & Misinterpretation </button>
        <button class="button" id="button2" draggable="true">Communication Delays</button>
        <button class="button" id="button3" draggable="true">Scattered Work and Content </button>
        <button class="button" id="button4" draggable="true">Sharing Work with Others</button>
        <button class="button" id="button5" draggable="true">Getting Feedback and Ideas
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-zone" style="border-color:#31CFDE">
    </div>
    <script>
    
    var draggableElement = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

for(var i = 0; i < draggableElement.length; i++) {
    draggableElement[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", this.id); 
    });
}

/*
const draggableElement = document.querySelector("#button1");
draggableElement.addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", draggableElement.id);
});
*/
for (const dropZone of document.querySelectorAll(".drop-zone")) {
  //when draggable element is over a dz
  dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropZone.classList.add("drop-zone--over");
  });
  //when draggable element no longer over dz
  dropZone.addEventListener("dragLeave", e => {
    dropZone.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
  });
  //when draggable element is dropped onto dz
  dropZone.addEventListener("drop", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const droppedElementId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    const droppedElement = document.getElementById(droppedElementId);
    dropZone.appendChild(droppedElement);
    dropZone.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
  });
}
  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```